# I have to read a file from an NSURL and have to save it locally

Tags: ios, macos

I am new in iOS programming. Can anyone help me that how i can read a .PDF file and save it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the PDF, then you can load it in **UIWebView**.

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

If you need to download the PDF and save it locally,

```
NSString *stringURL = URL_FOR_PDF;
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
  NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

  NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.png"];
  [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: I tried this one but still i cannot find the file after executing my app. everything just goes fine, no exception, no error but still no file downloaded.

Comment: thanks for the help man. it was working but i was looking for file in wrong directory. thanks alot.

Comment: i tried but i am not eligible to do so. as i have recently joined

Comment: sure with pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

see following links may be it's help you:

https://github.com/Ink/ThatPDF

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/roboreader

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pdf-reader-core